# Simplest way to create a resizable layout such as the one on apple's website?

Tags: html, css

I am interested in learning how to specify css styles such that four divs will always fill up the full width of the browser, but depending on how wide the browser is either 1, 2, or all 4 of the divs will be displayed per line. [Apple's website](http://www.apple.com) does this with their four smaller boxes of content underneath the main box of content.

I have tried this using @media although this might be the completely wrong approach.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>

        @media only screen and (min-width: 1068){
          #mainDiv {
           background-color: red;
           width: 100%;
           height: 200px;
          }
           #div1 {
            background-color: blue;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 25%;
            height: 200px;
           }
          #div2 {
            background-color: green;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 25%;
            height: 200px;
          }
          #div3 {
            background-color: yellow;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 25%;
            height: 200px;
          }
          #div4 {
            background-color: purple;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 25%;
            height: 200px;
          }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width: 735){
          #mainDiv {
            background-color: red;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
          }
          #div1 {
            background-color: blue;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50%;
            height: 200px;
          }
          #div2 {
            background-color: green;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50%;
            height: 200px;
          }
          #div3 {
            background-color: yellow;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50%;
            height: 200px;
          }
          #div4 {
            background-color: purple;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50%;
            height: 200px;
          }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 734){
          #mainDiv {
            background-color: red;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
          }
          #div1 {
            background-color: blue;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
          }
          #div2 {
            background-color: green;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
          }
          #div3 {
            background-color: yellow;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
          }
          #div4 {
            background-color: purple;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
          }
        }

  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

      <div id="mainDiv">
      </div>

      <div id="div1">
      </div>
      
      <div id="div2">
      </div>
      
      <div id="div3">
      </div>
      
      <div id="div4">
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Include the code you tried in this question. Also I would suggest you to see how apple's website uses css for its website. You might be able to understand something from there

Comment: you are looking for `css media queries`, that is what you want. Alternately, there are many `css frameworks` that can make this task a lot easier for you.

Comment: Look up responsive design. I recommend using something like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)  Here is a really quick example I have put together.  Click the "Full page" to play around with it and see how it works.

This is based on your updated question with the code snippet.  I basically added the `px` to your media queries, and used `max-width` instead of a combination of `max-width` and `min-width`.

```css
#mainDiv {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
#fourDivWrapper {
    font-size: 0px; /* A hack to prevent the space between */
}
#fourDivWrapper div {
    font-size: 14px;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
}
#div3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
}
#div4 {
  background-color: purple;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1067px){
  #div1 {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #div2 {
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #div3 {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #div4 {
    background-color: purple;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 734px){
  #div1 {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #div2 {
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #div3 {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #div4 {
    background-color: purple;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">Main div</div>

<div id="fourDivWrapper">
    <div id="div1">div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">div 2</div>
    <div id="div3">div 3</div>
    <div id="div4">div 4</div>
</div>
```

And here is the original answer:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .column {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column">a</div>
    <div class="column">b</div>
    <div class="column">c</div>
    <div class="column">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: No problem.  With your example that you have since added into your question, you are basically just missing the `px` in the media queries: `@media only screen and (min-width: 1068px)` instead of `@media only screen and (min-width: 1068)`, and some specific ordering.  I'll update my answer to be more specific to your example.